# SQL user defined aggregate order of values preserved?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, clr, user-defined-aggregate

Im using the code from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx) to create a user defined aggregate to concatenate strings with `group by's` in SQL server. One of my requirements is that the order of the concatenated values are the same as in the query. For example:

```
Value   Group
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
```

Using query

```
SELECT
  dbo.Concat(tbl.Value) As Concat,
  tbl.Group
FROM
  (SELECT TOP 1000
     tblTest.*
  FROM 
    tblTest
  ORDER BY 
    tblTest.Value) As tbl
GROUP BY
  tbl.Group
```

Would result in:

```
Concat  Group
"1,2"   1
"3,4"   2
```

The result seems to always come out correct and as expected, but than I came across [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedaggregateattribute.isinvarianttoorder.aspx) that states that the order is not guaranteed and that attribute `SqlUserDefinedAggregateAttribute.IsInvariantToOrder` is only reserved for future use.

So my question is: Is it correct to assume that the concatenated values in the string can end up in any order? 
If that is the case then why does the example code on the MSDN page use the `IsInvariantToOrder` attribute?

Comment: Can't answer your MS question, but `GROUP_CONCAT` allows you to be deterministic about the concatenation.

Comment: @kerrek - note this is tagged `SQL Server` not `MySQL`

Comment: I'm afraid there is no `GROUP_CONCAT` in SQL server 2008

Comment: @JNK: Oh, isn't that standard SQL? Never mind in that case!

Comment: If your order is entirely dependent on the values that are concatenated you could mange the order in the C# code. I'm no C# coder but mucked around with it a bit so it produced the reverse order using insert instead of append on the `stringbuilder`. I guess you could sort the string in `Terminate()` before it is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mikael, but this is part of a View that is used by multiple other queries, so it would be very messy to change all those to do it in code instead.

Comment: @Magnus – Hu? I mean that you could modify the Concat C# code you got from MSDN. No need to modify the queries or the views.

Comment: @Mikael ok, I see what you mean. But I do not always need to order by the values being concatenated, but by some other field in query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect a big problem here is your statement "the same as in the query" - however, your query ***never*** defines (and cannot define) an order by the things being aggregated (you can of course order the *groups*, by having a `ORDER BY` after the `GROUP BY`). Beyond that, I can only say that it is based purely on a *set* (rather than an ordered sequence), and that *technically* the order is indeed undefined.

Comment: +1 - Search for `SQL Order` on SO and you will get a lot of posts about similar issues.

Comment: You can specify `order by` if you have `top` statement of an inner select and than group by on that.

Comment: @Marc I've updated my question with a query that's using an inner select with `top` statement and `order by`. Will the end result of using group by and `Concat` on that still have an undefined order?

Comment: @Magnus - all that that inner `ORDER BY` gives you is a sound definition for `TOP`. It *does not*, by any means, guarantee the order in which any outer operations will operate on the rows. Indeed, people used to use `TOP 100 PERCENT` and `ORDER BY` to "order" views - but then the optimizer was smartened to realize that it doesn't need to perform an ordering if 100% of the rows are required. If the same optimization hasn't occurred for inner queries yet, it may well do in the next release of SQL Server.

Comment: @Marc, ok thanks. Strange thing is that it always does follow the inner order by in my test.

Comment: If they implement that "optimization" in the next version maybe they will also implement `IsInvariantToOrder` to fix it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe that optimization has been implemented for inner queries now. The intra-group order no longer persists when I try cross applying a subquery with ORDER BY inside.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct, I wanted to share a workaround that others may find useful. Warning: it involves not using a user-defined aggregate at all :)

The link below describes an elegant way to build a concatenated, delimited list using only a SELECT statement and a varchar variable. The upside (for this thread) is that you can specify the order in which the rows are processed. The downside is that you can't easily concatenate across many different subsets of rows without painful iteration.

Not perfect, but for my use case was a good workaround.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/

Comment: Although that can not be used with a group by as in my question.

Comment: Yep, exactly - that was what I was trying to get at by saying "the downside is that..."

Comment: How would you specify an order in this case? If this is inside a view or function, it is still impossible to specify an order, making this useless.

Comment: To specify an order in which you process the rows for the delimited list, you would do: `DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Name
FROM Production.Product ORDER BY Name -- or whatever`. You are correct that this involves using procedural code (a variable declaration), which means it can't be used inside a view or function. But it can be used inside a SP. I would argue that this workaround is not "useless" just because it isn't relevant for your specific situation.

Comment: @MikeMonteiro The problem here would be the `ORDER BY` clause, not the variable declaration, which AFAIK is OK in a scalar function. The reason I said this is useless is because there is no way to use this in subqueries, functions, or views, unless you skip ordering of the result, which is the whole point of the question. Trying to use this with a sproc never occurred to me.